# Export intrinsic camera parameters in Blender via .gltf file

Tags: python, blender, gltf, dataloader, camera-intrinsics

I am working on a .gltf data loader in python for the quite popular [multi-NeRF](https://github.com/google-research/multinerf) framework.

I exported the 3D model in Blender as a `.gltf` file with the appropriate export settings which means that I also ticked the blender camera in the settings to have the extrinsic camera parameters in the `.gltf` file.

For the data loader in multi-NeRF there already exists a [base class](https://github.com/google-research/multinerf/blob/main/internal/datasets.py#L152) which someone can use for creating custom data loaders. This base class has some minimum aquirements regarding data to work with like for example the extrinsic/intrinsic camera parameters and distortion coefficients etc.

So, my question is how to get the intrinsic camera parameters/distortion coefficients from the Blender camera in order to export them via the `.gltf` file like the extrinsic camera parameters? Thanks for any help!

Comment: You can find the camera properties that glTF supports in the [specification](https://registry.khronos.org/glTF/specs/2.0/glTF-2.0.html#cameras). If you want to export anything it doesn't support, those would have to be put into "Custom Properties" in Blender, and extracted manually in whatever you're using to load the glTF file.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.